# How can I see the changes I make to a Go app running in Heroku local?

Tags: go, heroku

I admit I'm a GoLang newbie. In an attempt to learn Go, I developed an app about a year ago (based on [the Heroku Getting started repository](https://github.com/heroku/go-getting-started)) and deployed it to Heroku. I used the `heroku local` server to develop it locally and deployed it successfully. Now I want to make some changes but I don't have the original source, so I have cloned the app from the Heroku repository.

I have got it running locally with the following steps:

1. `export GOPATH=~/project_path`
2. `export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin`
3. `go get`
4. `go install`
5. `heroku local`

So far, so good. The problem is that when I make a simple change to the code in `main.go`, it doesn't show up in the browser. I've tried running `go install` and restarting the server after making the change but it makes no difference.

I've noticed that the file name in the Procfile is now incorrect (`go-getting-started` instead of the name of my project folder) but the server still runs and changing the name doesn't make any difference, locally at least. Same goes for the Dockerfile.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you make a change to a Go file in the project you need to run `go install` and stop and restart the heroku local server.

You might want to just run the server yourself with `PORT=5000 go run main.go` so that you only have to restart one thing. Or you can check out something like https://github.com/pilu/fresh which will listen to filesystem changes and restart your server for you.

Comment: I am running to install after making the changes and restarting the server.

Comment: Running the go server directly works correctly, so I guess the problem must lie with Heroku somehow.